How can I hide std::function internals in the stack trace?
When debugging and breaking inside a called std::function, 5 out of the 4 frames are unnecessary implementation details. E.g.:
#0  operator()  # my lambda
#1  std::__invoke_impl
#2  std::__invoke_r
#3  std::_Function_handler
#4  std::function
#5  operator()  # my other lambda
#6  std::__invoke_impl
#7  std::__invoke_r
#8  std::_Function_handler
#9  std::function
#10 ...  # sigh

Is there a way to hide or skip the implementation details? E.g. a vscode extension, gdb option, gdb script, other debuggers that support this?
Some similar questions have been asked about stepping into function in the debugger e.g:
How can I skip the method calls in the std namespace when stepping through a std::function invocation? (Using GDB.)
Also skipping past standard library calls, e.g. that appear in arguments to a function:
Tell gdb to skip standard files
However, this question is specifically just about avoiding clutter in the stack trace.

Have you seen this repo and the related presentation? I know I'm not giving you the actual answer, but I guess that's a good starting point.

In general, a debugger that hides what actually happened and presents a "sugar-coated" picture will end in tears. It will work 99% of the time, but then you'll spend many days trying to understand something, and will discover that if you remove the sugar coating, the problem would have been obvious from the start.
